# GWT How to give an Animation a 3D Effect?

Tags: java, animation, gwt

I have followed [this tutorial](http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=1548) to produce an animation using GWT. From this I have been able to animate a ball being pitched and then hit. The code is:

```
protected void play1(){
    // Baseball ball animation 1.

    //"Hit" the ball to left field
    absolutePanel.add(img, 300, 400);
    CustomAnimation animation2 = new CustomAnimation(img.getElement());
    animation2.scrollTo(10, 10, 5000);

    //Place the ball with the pitcher and pitch to the batter.
    absolutePanel.add(img, 300, 300);
    CustomAnimation animation1 = new CustomAnimation(img.getElement());
    animation1.scrollTo(300, 450, 1000);

}
```

This shows a ground ball quite well. What I want to do is show a ball being hit in an arch to the same position with a 3D effect to differentiate between a ground ball and a fly ball.

Your help in letting me know how to do this would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: Did you consider to use CSS animation ?

Comment: Hi @jdramaix, No, I have not heard of this. I will look it up if you think it will achieve what I am after. Thanks, Glyn

Comment: Hi @jdramaix, This looks quite good and will probably do what I want if I can get it to work. I will start a separate question in relation to my issues with this. Thanks, Glyn

Comment: Hi @jdramaix, I have been able to get this to work in 2D (i.e., as a replacement for the code I already have). Thank you very much for that. However, I am having difficulty in transforming it to 3D as per my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26601336/how-to-convert-a-css3-2d-animatuon-to-a-3d-transform Regards, Glyn